# Laravel show date on front end which is closest to today

Tags: php, date, laravel, frontend, backend

For my model (workshop) i have a field called ‘date’, this input shows the user on which date this workshop is. I would like to enter multiple dates (comma separated) via the back-end and show the user on the front-end the date that is closest to the current date. 
In my previous attempts i was unable to save a array to the database and so unable to show the user on the front end, one of these dates.

Is there a easy way to create such thing I mentioned above and is it easy??

What i previously had:

```
public function store()
    {
        if(Input::hasFile('file'))
        {
            $file               = Input::file('file');
            $destinationPath    = 'uploads/images/workshops/';
            $filename           = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $upload_success     = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        }

        $new_workshop = array(
            'concept'   => Input::get('concept'),
            'title'     => Input::get('title'),
            'body'      => Input::get('body'),
            'author'    => Input::get('author'),
            'slug'      => Str::slug(Input::get('title')),
            'image'     => str_replace('\\', '/', $upload_success),
            $thedate = array();
            foreach(explode(',',Input::get('date')) as $date){
               array_push($thedate,$date);
            }
            'date'      => $thedate,
        );
        $rules = array(
            'title'     => 'required|min:3|max:255',
            'body'      => 'required|min:10',
            'date'      => 'required',
        );

        $validation = Validator::make($new_workshop, $rules);
        if ( $validation->fails() )
        {
            return Redirect::route('admin.workshops.create')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
        }
        $workshop = new Workshop($new_workshop);
        $workshop->save(); 

        return Redirect::route('admin.workshops.index');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implode the array. This will put it into a string for you.

Multiple inputs;

```
<input name="date[]".... /> //one for one date 
<input name="date[]".... /> //one for another date
```

Above all depends on how you are setting the date on the page. Aslong as the date have date[] in the name it will populate the Input::get('date');

Then change;

```
$thedate = array();
foreach(explode(',',Input::get('date')) as $date){
     array_push($thedate,$date);
}
'date'      => $thedate,
```

to

```
'date' => implode(',',Input::get('date')),
```

And the saved value will be 'date','date'... depending on the amount of date you have posted.

If your only using a single input and separating the date with a , all you have to do is;

Change

```
$thedate = array();
foreach(explode(',',Input::get('date')) as $date){
     array_push($thedate,$date);
}
'date'      => $thedate,
```

to

```
'date' => Input::get('date'),
```

Comment: Hehe matt, that is exactly what i don't want, i want to create a array from a string (i enter in a input field, comma separated) and use some code over it to show the user on the front end the date that is closest (in the future).

Comment: But you cannot store the array as the data.

Comment: Oh ok, lol did not know that. I'm trying out your implode version, but i'm getting weird errors, "implode(): Invalid arguments passed " Should i just follow my code, and replace explode with implode ?

Comment: K great this gets me in the right direction, thanks matt! Now all i have to do is write some code to show only the closest date.